# this code is not running because of problems in arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Basically the code is giving error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

in two different lines

I looked for other functions to work with arrays but nothing worked

```
pulse = np.array((-1/(math.sqrt(2*pi)/(dev **3))) * term)

pulse = pulse*np.array(math.exp((-0.500/dev**2)*term ** 2)) # the error happens here
```

because of the expression: `math.exp((-0.500/dev ** 2)*term**2)`

```
spectrum = w*math.exp(-1*w*mean)*math.exp(-1 * w ** 2 * (dev ** 2 / 2)) # here the same error
```

Comment: Please post the entire program. We don't know exactly what is wrong until you show us the entire program. That error in particular is usually because you are trying to use a function meant for a single number on an array

Comment: What are `dev` and `term`?  Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: `math.exp` only works with scalars, single numbers.  You get this error if you pass it an array with more than one value.  `np.exp` will work with array inputs.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, math functions `math.exp` work on scalar numbers, so when you pass arrays to them, they will fail. You might want to use numpy equivalent functions.

In general, numpy is comprehensive enough, to eliminate the need of using any math function. See the code below where a simply array is defined and how each of two *exp* functions in *numpy* and *math* behave:

```py
import math
import numpy as np

a1  = np.array([1,2,3])
ea1 = np.exp(a1)

ea2 = math.exp(a1)
```

When using `np.exp` in the code above, you will get an array:

> array([ 2.71828183,  7.3890561 , 20.08553692])

When using `math.exp` in the code above, you will get following error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

So, your code will work when you use numpy functions as below:

```py
pulse = -1/(np.sqrt(2*pi)/(dev **3)) * term
pulse = pulse * np.exp((-0.500/dev**2)*term ** 2)
spectrum = w * np.exp(-1*w*mean) * np.exp(-1 * w ** 2 * (dev ** 2 / 2))
```